# Jest tests are failing on Bitbucket Pipelines due to snapshots differing on dates / times

Tags: node.js, bitbucket, jestjs, bitbucket-pipelines

As in subject, tests which passes locally are failing on snapshots in Bitbucket Pipelines. What differs are fields containing dates/times. The difference is exactly one hour.

```
   @@ -15812,11 +15812,11 @@
                   >
                     <div
                       className="well"
                     >
                       Data collected: 
-                      2018-5-4 17:17:49
+                      2018-5-4 16:17:49
                     </div>
                     <div
                       className="panel-group"
                       id="deviceInfo"
                     >
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems obvious that this is caused by the difference in locale setting between my machine and the environment on Bitbucket where tests run. I sorted this out by setting timezone in the environment variable in the bitbucket-pipelines.yml file:

```
        ...
        script:
        - export TZ='Europe/London'
        ...
```